# Swift tableView.reloadData() seems not working

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift

I've just created a new project using `CoreData` with the "`Master-Detail Application`" template. I'm using the code provided by Apple, I just added a `NSPrediate` in the fetchController

```
        var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
        if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Event", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity

        // Here the code i added <<<<<<<<
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "year = %d", self.selectedYear)

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timeStamp", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {
             // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
             // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
             //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
             abort()
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }
```

where `selected.Year` is a simple `var`. I also added a UIButton connected to an `IBAction` that will change the value of `selectedYear`.

```
    @IBAction func changeYear(sender: AnyObject) {
            self.selectedYear = self.selectedYear + 1
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

(I logged the func `changeYear` and it's called)

So after that i'm calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` to update the `UITableView` that should now fetch different records depending on the new predicate, but the `tableView` is never updated 
(I tried to log the delegate methods but are never fired).
What am i missing?

I also tried to make the `tableView` an `IBOutlet` from `storyboard` and tried to call `self.tv.reloadData()`, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fetched results controller does not work this way. You need to tell it to re-fetch based on the new predicate:

```
_fetchedResultsController = nil
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

The other way is to change the predicate of the fetch request of the FRC and call

```
self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch(&error)
```

Then there is no need to reload the table with `reloadData()` because the delegate should take care of it. But I presume that you are completely replacing the contents of the table, so the above solution is probably easier and just as performant.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks that was it! Anyway for anyone using this template you should call `_fetchedResultController = nil` and not `self.fetchedResultController = nil`